# Query two databases in the same server

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two databases in the same server and I need to:

```
Select from table1 (in database1) the id field
Where notific1=1
```

But only the `user_id` list

```
Where in table2 (in database2) the enabled field=1
```

Being the user_id field in the two tables the same.

I tried:

```
SELECT table1.id 
    FROM [database1].[dbo].[table1] as users
    INNER JOIN [database2].[dbo].[table2] as subs
    ON users.user_id=subs.user_id
    WHERE users.notific1=1 AND
    WHERE subs.enabled=1
```

This is throwing the error:

> .#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[database1].[dbo].[table1] as users INNER JOIN [database2].[dbo]' at line 2

NOTE: I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not have 2 where as you did ( since you tagged your question with Mysql)

```
WHERE users.notific1=1 AND
WHERE subs.enabled=1
```

It should be

```
WHERE 
users.notific1=1 
AND
subs.enabled=1
```

Also while JOINING the 2 databases the syntax is

```
select * from proj1.users as y 
inner join project2.users f on f.email = y.email 
and y.email = 'abhik@xxxx.com'
```

`proj1` and `project2` are 2 databases in the same server and `users` is the tables in those databases.

Comment: usually while joining 2 databases and as you marked mysql it should be something as `databasename.tablename` something as `select * from proj1_dev.users as y inner join project2.users f on f.email = y.email and y.email = 'abhik@xxxx.com';`

Answer (score 0):

For mysql, the `square brackets []` are not used for object names.
Use back ticks instead

```
SELECT table1.id 
    FROM `database1`.`table1` as users
    INNER JOIN `database2`.`table2` as subs
    ON users.user_id=subs.user_id
    WHERE users.notific1=1 AND
    subs.enabled=1
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a `dbo` schema in MySql as as per SqlServer. Just drop the dbo:

```
SELECT table1.id 
    FROM database1.table1 as users
    INNER JOIN database2.table2 as subs
    ON users.user_id=subs.user_id
    WHERE users.notific1=1 AND
    WHERE subs.enabled=1
```

Answer (score 0):

"where" is written two time..

try below:

```
SELECT table1.id 
    FROM database1.dbo.table1 as users
    INNER JOIN database2.dbo.table2 as subs
    ON users.user_id=subs.user_id
    WHERE users.notific1=1 AND
 subs.enabled=1
```

Answer (score 0):

***OR Condition***

```
SELECT u1.*, 
       u2.* 
FROM   db1.table1 u1 
       INNER JOIN db2.table2 u2 
               ON u1.id = u2.id 
WHERE  u1.id IN( '12', '16' ) ** 
       OR ** u2.id = 17
```

***AND Condition***

```
SELECT u1.*, 
       u2.* 
FROM   db1.table1 u1 
       INNER JOIN db2.table2 u2 
               ON u1.id = u2.id 
WHERE  u1.id IN( '12', '16' ) ** 
       AND ** u2.id != ''
```